# How do I start a workflow automatically when a document enters an existing library from a different library?

Tags: workflow

I am using a pre-workflow to move a document to an existing library after the recipient completes the task. Once it enters the new library I want it to automatically start the main workflow. Is this possible?

All workflows are already set to start when created and/or changed. I created the workflows in SharePoint designer 2013. The form that is being moved was made in infopath designer 2013.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The scenario is as follows:
Source: **Source Document Library**
Workflow: **Pre-Workflow** --> It will move the document from **Source Document Library** to **Target Document Library**

Target: **Target Document Library**
Workflow: **Main Workflow**--> This is should execute once any document is getting created or updated by **Pre-Workflow**
Execution Policy: On Creation/Updation of Document in **Target Document Library**

Problem: **Main Workflow** is not getting executed by **Pre-Workflow**, once any document is getting created.

*

> [Please correct me if the scenario is something else.]

*
Solution:

1. If you run the **Pre-Workflow** using **System Account**, then **Main Workflow** will not be started automatically. So please start the **Pre-Workflow** using any other account than **System Account**. Log in to the site using other account than **System Account**
2. If the **Main Workflow** is not getting executed after changing the log in account. Add a step in the **Pre-Workflow** by which you need to update a test metadata field in the newly created item in the **Target Document Library**. This step needs to be executed after copying of the document in the **Target Document Library**. By doing this the **Main Workflow** will be executed on change of the document.

> Above solution should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the 'main workflow' is attached to the new library and set to start upon creation of a new item, even if the new item is dumped in there via another workflow, the 'main workflow' should start without a problem.

Comment: The 'Main workflow' is attached to the new library, but it will not start unless I manually do it or change the item. Sharepoint does seem to recognize an item being dumped into library as "created".

Comment: And you are positive that the workflow is set to trigger when a new item is created? Is it a list workflow or a reusable workflow? I actually just finished a project where I am moving a completed Infopath form from one library to another and the destination library has a workflow that is set to trigger when the item is copied ove.

Comment: I'm using a list workflow. The "pre-workflow" is platform type: "sharepoint 2010 workflow" and the "main workflow" is platform type: "sharepoint 2013 workflow" if that matters. I need the exact same scenario as you have made and if can figure out whats going wrong, then i'll be done with my project also! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you make sure the 'main workflow' is set to trigger when a new item is created?  Sometimes it's easy to forget!  Also, just to be clear, which workflow is copying the item over to the new library?  Are you using the Copy Item action?

Comment: The "pre workflow" will copy the item over once the task is completed like this :                                                Step: Step 1
 Assign From Accounting Department to Current Item:Account Id,---
 Copy item in Current Item to Purchase Order Forms,---
 Delete item in Current Item
-------------------------------------------------- Once it copies over to "Purchase Order Forms" the workflow should start automatically. I made sure the "start when created was checked". Maybe if i disable the option to be start manually also, it may work.

Comment: Based on your description, it should work.  Did you look in the workflow history logs to to make sure some silent error didn't pop up?

Comment: Do you think deleting current item from the old library after it's copied has anything to do with it not functioning properly? I don't see any errors popping up in the workflow history log during or after "pre workflow" is completed.

Comment: No, not at all.  I delete the items also once they are copied over.  It's kind of risky since Designer Workflows don't have any exception handling capabilities.  Depending on how big the workflow is, you may try deleting it and recreating it in case some mysterious bug is in it.  Also, don't know how you published your infopath form, but you could try publishing it as a content type and then add it to both libraries.

Comment: Here's one idea: try adding an impersonation step in your Pre-Workflow at the point where the item is copied.  This will copy the item over to the new list using your credentials instead of system account.  Sometimes workflows don't trigger when they are running under the System Account id.

Comment: I still haven't figured it out, but if there is a way to change the form once it reaches the main library then it would kick off the workflow. The workflow is set to kick off when the form is changed, so if i could change something through the workflow with out any one else noticing that might be an option. Any ideas?

Comment: I am really curious why the workflow is not triggering when the item is copied over.  It sounds like you are in SP2013 and that is the reason why things are happening the way they should--this works without issue in 2010 as I have currently deployed forms using this technique.

Comment: Oh you're in sharepoint 2010! That makes more sense now why this is happening to me. We just upgraded (not optional) to sharepoint 2013. I'm going to have to figure out a way to change the form with a workflow after it has been moved to the new folder, i believe that may trigger it.